# c++ openGL picking problems

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a little example, where I have loaded an object from a wavefront file - and am trying to get my picking right, I've gone over this and a few tutorials about 10 times... but must be missing something. Was wondering if anyone could provide an extra set of eyes.

I've used a saved list to draw the object, which appears fine on the screen... At the moment, when gl_select(x, y) runs, I get a hit no matter what, and if I enable the translate/rotate code (which is currently commented out) - I get no hits what-so-ever.

Relevant code blocks:

```
// gl_select, is called when the mouse is clicked, with its x and y coords
void gl_select(int x, int y)
{
    GLuint buff[256];
    GLint hits;
    GLint view[4];

    //Buffer to store selection data
    glSelectBuffer(256, buff);

    //Viewport information
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);

    //Switch to select mode
    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

    //Clear the name stack!
    glInitNames();

    //Fill the stack with one element
    glPushName(0);

    //Restric viewing volume
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Restrict draw area
    gluPickMatrix(x, y, 1.0, 1.0, view);
    gluPerspective(60, 1, 0.0001, 1000.0);

    //Draw the objects onto the screen
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    //Draw only the names in the stack
    glutSwapBuffers();
    DrawSavedObject();

    //Back into projection mode to push the matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);

    cout << hits;

    //Back to modelview mode
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

And the draw functions:

```
void DrawSavedObject()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

    //translate and rotate
    //glRotated(rotation,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    //glTranslated(7.0, 7.0, 0.0);

    //Draw the saved object
    glLoadName(7);
    glCallList(list_object);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And where the list is saved:

```
void SaveDisplayList(){     
    glNewList(list_object, GL_COMPILE);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 3*sizeof(GLdouble), vertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, verticesSize ,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, triangles);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glEndList();
}
```

Sorry again for the chunkiness of the code blocks.

Comment: What was the dolution after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider here:

- OpenGL selection mode is deprecated and never was HW accelerated, except on a few SGI boxes and 3DLabs GPUs.
- DisplayLists don't mix with Vertex Arrays.
- Why do you call *glutSwapBuffers* right before drawing your list of saved objects? Makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Cheers, looks like I'll be having a conversation with my lecturer about the serious outdatedness of the unit/code examples.

Comment: If selection mode is deprecated, what is the current preferred method for picking objects?

Comment: @Mr.Shickadance: There's not kitchen sink solution for the problem. One normally chooses what fits the application the best. There are (among others) ray/bounding volume/geometry intersection testing, index/colour buffer picking, projection of bounding volume hierachy into screen space into spatial subdivision structures (like Kd or Quadtrees), and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's relevant but you're not supposed to store things like `glVertexPointer` in display lists. From the spec http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glNewList.xml:

> Certain commands are not compiled into the display list but are
>   executed immediately, regardless of the display-list mode. These
>   commands are glAreTexturesResident, glColorPointer, glDeleteLists,
>   glDeleteTextures, glDisableClientState, glEdgeFlagPointer,
>   glEnableClientState, glFeedbackBuffer, glFinish, glFlush, glGenLists,
>   glGenTextures, glIndexPointer, glInterleavedArrays, glIsEnabled,
>   glIsList, glIsTexture, glNormalPointer, glPopClientAttrib,
>   glPixelStore, glPushClientAttrib, glReadPixels, glRenderMode,
>   glSelectBuffer, glTexCoordPointer, glVertexPointer, and all of the
>   glGet commands.

This could be what's causing your problem.